# How long is the penalty for Duplicate ecommerce content after it has been ressurected

Tags: google-search, web-crawlers

I am fixing all of the duplicate content on my ecommerce site with all orignal descriptions etc. How long does it take google to start ranking it again? I used to have a good ranking that converted quite a few sales, in the last week i have had next to nothing.

Also would the disclaimer i created under each product be considered duplicate content because it is on most of my product pages & is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Google's suggestion regarding duplicate content and re-indexing "Once you've made your changes and are confident that your site no longer violates our guidelines, submit your site for reconsideration."

Reconsideration Requests: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35843

Same disclaimer on each product page will be considered duplicate content, you should place it at footer or sidebar.

Comment: There is no harm in the same disclaimer text on every product page providing it makes up a small percentage of the overall visible content.